# Перезаписать применение print в рамках класса

Tags: python

Существует ли возможность перезаписать print в Python в рамках класса по аналогии с магическими методами?

Comment: да - `def __str__`

Comment: вот `__str__` и `__repr__` [подробно тут](https://pyneng.readthedocs.io/ru/old_chapter_order/book/26_oop_special_methods/str_repr.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
class A():
    def __str__(self):
        return "hello"
a = A()
print(a)
```

> ```
> hello
> ```

Comment: Добавьте, пожалуйста, объяснения. А то получается ответ для тех кто уже знает ответ.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Вы отчасти правы, но я считаю, что чего-то писать надо тогда, когда непонятно из примера. Пример очевидной ИМХО.

Comment: Пару слов: "`print` вызывает у объектов `__str__`, а если печатаем контейнер, то будет вызван `__repr__`. А если нет одного, то вызывается другой, ...". Как-то даже не пара получилась. :)